# Windows 10 - How to change startup behaviour in update 1709

Tags: windows-10-v1709

The recent update (1709) has changed the behavior about running the applications at startup under this registry key:

```
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
```

I added a program under this key and It would automatically run when I sign in to Windows. But after this update, the program runs BEFORE I sign in, i.e. as soon as Windows is booted. How could I to revert to old behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution...

you can use these steps:

1. Open Settings.
2. Click on Accounts.
3. Click on Sign-in options.
4. Under "Privacy," turn off the **"Use my sign-in info to automatically finish setting up my device after an update or restart"** toggle switch.

[Credits](https://www.windowscentral.com/windows-10-fall-creators-update-common-installation-problems-and-fixes#fix_fall_creators_update_apps_auto_restart)

Answer (score 1):

Run and RunOnce registry keys make the programs to run each time user logs in, so probably your program (after update) is registered somewhere else too.
check settings/privacy/background apps, you can turn it on or off there. also in task manager/startup, you can change the impact/priority of the program.

Comment: I've confirmed by sysinternels autoruns.exe, and no other instance exists except under this registry key.